# Use the Beta endpoint in the Graph Toolkit in SharePoint spfx

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I want to fetch data from Graph from the new beta versions, specifically the user profiles.
When specifying the following code

```
    let provider = new SharePointProvider(this.context);
    provider.graph = BetaGraph.fromGraph(provider.graph);
    Providers.globalProvider = provider;
```

I get the following error in the WebPart:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined at Function.fromGraph`

Any advise? Do I need to specify the graph context object to connect to the beta endpoint somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Frank-Ove Kristiansen,

You can set the version on a specific request by using the version

```
Providers.globalProvider.graph.client.api('/users').version('beta').get().then(v => {
    console.log(v);
});
```

And in `mgt-get`, it has a [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/get#properties-and-attributes) parameter:

```
<mgt-get resource="/me" version="beta"
```

//////////////////////////////
**Update**:

I found the reason. . `BetaGraph.fromGraph` will access `Graph.client` and use it to initialize a new betagraph instance. However  `onInit()` is an asynchronous method, at that time, `client` or `graph` is not available, thus it will prompt "undefined" error.

We can put `provider.graph = BetaGraph.fromGraph(provider.graph);` in another method. for example, i put it in the constructor of my react componment:

[image]

Then it works fine, all requests are using beta endpoints

BR

Comment: I need to fetch the beta version when using the `<Person>` component. This has no version property. Will the first example apply to my whole WebPart, on all my components?